# Automatic Databinding of controls to Model

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have developed a prototype framework (MVVM) where control on the form is bound to a model property using a naming convention and its UI behavior is controlled using custom attributes.

1. As of now the control name is divided into two parts - 3 part prefix and then the Name of the property in model to bind to.

   For eg `txtFirstName` textbox is bound to `FirstName` in model. During construction/load, all controls are looped through -

   ```
   BaseEdit baseEdit = (BaseEdit) control;
   baseEdit.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", viewModelBindingSource,
                             baseEdit.Name.Remove(0, 3),
                             true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
   ```

   There are some other attributes such as **[ReadOnly], [Unbound]** which are used to control the UI behavior.

   ```
   baseEdit.Properties.ReadOnly = Util.GetReadOnlyAttributeValue(
       control.Name.Remove(0, 3), viewModel.GetType());
   ```

   I am thinking of doing the looping the other way around, ie the Model properties, using a `Bound` attribute. `Bound[ControlName, PropertyName]`

   ```
   Bound["txtFirstName", "EditValue"]
   FirstName
   ```
2. All the dropdown type controls, combobox, dropdown, checkeddropdown etc **are autofilled by using a 'Key' from their tag property**.

   ```
   if (control.GetType() == typeof(LookUpEdit) && 
       !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(control.Tag))) //Exact match
   {
          LookUpEdit lookUpEdit = (LookUpEdit)control;
          DataBinding.InitializeLookUpEdit(lookUpEdit, lookUpEdit.Tag.ToString()); 
   }
   ```

   I took the biggest data-entry form with around 45 controls and tested the framework.

Is the above approach suitable for a big project? Any suggestions for improving the framework?

Comment: Do you have a sample project so that it can be tested?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an architectural review as opposed to a code review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO Anything that relies on controls' `Tag` property is fishy. In 15 years of VB4-5-6/VBA and then WinForms development, every single time I saw the `Tag` property assigned, there was a better way to solve the problem. I think using that property more often than not violates the *principle of least surprise (POLS)*, because it's not *typical* to put anything in there - if anything it means a control is begging to be derived from that control's class, and featured with the relevant properties - which is obviously too much trouble to be worth the while.

That's my rant against using the `Tag` property. That said it looks rather clean, much cleaner than [this similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/23847/23788), but it suffers from the same issue:

> WinForms applications are better off with the **Model-View-Presenter** pattern.
> [...] if you want to simulate WPF behavior in WinForms, the *real thing* will be much less trouble, and leave you with much cleaner code.
>
> Sorry if that's not what you wanted to hear...

For a big project I'd seriously consider either MVP or MVVM with WPF.

Comment: The overall architecture is MVP-VM, with a base framework for automatic databinding. Working nicely right now.